# Replacing boolean values in JSON using powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I'm trying to update a boolean value inside a JSON formated file using powershell but I'm not getting the required output.

From the below,

```
{
"setComputerName":  false,
"setWallpaper":  true
}
```

I would like to get the output as,

```
{
"setComputerName":  true,
"setWallpaper":  true
}
```

Below is my script,

```
$file = Get-Content 'C:\temp\Config.json' -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$file = $file.setComputerName = 'true'
$file | ConvertTo-Json  | set-content 'C:\temp\Config1.json'
```

Comment: Hi. For future reference, it's always a good idea to post the incorrect output (or exception details) along with the desired output, so that people can get a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: @DeanOC I agree

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you have to do once you import your json is.

```
$file.setComputerName=$true
$file | ConvertTo-Json  | set-content 'C:\temp\Config1.json'
```

You were trying to set the value as a string and it needs to be boolean, so you need to use $true or $false in order to set those values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is it. Worked genuinely. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @CDP-cdp No problem at all!